# How to go to translate tool by python script?

Tags: python

I would like to know how to go into translate mode by python code.
What I want to do is not like moving object directly by using operator but I just want to do
The thing that happens after I pressed G key for translate tool in Edit Mode by Python code.
I’m not sure it can be simply done or not but if you know how, please tell me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: There is no build in way to enter the grab function with python. If you are writing a macro for edit mode is faking a "g" key press in script an option?

Comment: Have a look at the text editor > templates > Operator Modal and Operator Modal View3d.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT', True)
```

This will enable the <kbd>G</kbd> mode (i.e. translate/move).